# TCP or HTTP for a javascript web-application?

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, tcp

Me and some friends from uni are making a javascript based web-application in our spare time.

now we have run into the question of whether we should use HTTP requests to communicate with the web-server behind the scenes of it all.

The application is going to be a small game where you should be able to click buttons to increase different statistics and stuff like that.

Is the smartest thing to have use http and have ajax polling to keep the client side updated or should we use tcp sockets and have a two-way stream of communication with the web-server?

Or should we use tcp sockets? because im not sure how that should work with javascript on the client side

further info:

the plan so far has been to use JAX-RS to communicate with the server (since thats what we were taught in a web-tec class at school) and the server side stuff will be programmed in java.

Thanks for any advice you might have